# Gettting a reload page call to fire only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, reload

im in a little bit of a pickle.

I have a complicated page, it has a lot of animations that change based on the size of the screen.

I use media queries and Jquery to edit the animations and stylings based on the screen size, but if say, for example, the animated DIV isn't in its starting position when the user decides to resize the screen. Sometimes, I can get some messed up stylings.

So I wanna try and reload the page and I wanna use an .on('mouseup') function to fire it.

This is to simulate the user Resizing the screen to their preferred range and then onrelease the screen reloads.

I tried .on('resize') but with that every time the user resizes between a certain range you get a reload, that is likely to slow down the user experience, especially with poor connections.

So here is my attempt at this, but its not working right.

```
$(window).on('mouseup', function(){

    if ($(window).width() <=775 && $(window).width() >= 481){
        location.reload();

    } else if ($(window).width() <=480 && $(window).width() >= 300){
        location.reload();

    }

});
```

As Im posting this I see an issue with the logic though, even if this did work. 
This would fire on accidental clicks because isnt anything in the window considerd part of the window? Or is it only the borders of the browser window itself.

Is something like this possible on('mouseup','resize', function(){})
sorry if I sound ike a code newb, but I am one

edit: I did try this mouse up resize suggestion exactly as I put here, but it didn't work. (Probaby because I did it wrong or its not possible)

Comment: You should fix your CSS to work correctly.  Reloading on resize is **extremely** annoying.

Comment: Yeah, I should have explained that better. 

Its hard to explain it with out seeing the page, but their are various phases of these animations. I dont think I could make rules that would retoactively fix them without effecting how the animations work, or how the screen looks. 


For example, on mobile screens, theirs a div that swipes back and forth on a button click. 

If left in its swiped state, going to a large screen the div gets stuck their.

Comment: I have no intention on reloading on resize, as I pointed out above its definitely annoying. 

In theory, most users dont resize their pages all day long like developers do, and this is really only an issue that shows up when the page is in certain states and is resized. 

I might just leave it, but its bugging me

Comment: Yah I agree with @SLaks that this problem should have been solved in the CSS layer not in the JS layer. I understand animations are difficult to work with multi-devices. But a little better preplanning on what animations are actually cross-device would have helped you out 5 steps ago versus trying to solve it here in the behaviorial level.

Answer (score 0):

Well, along with agreeing with the comments, that you shouldn't reload the page. Rather your app should have states and the states can always be reset to the starting point.

**BUT**

if you want the page to reload only once as your title suggests you can store a variable in `localStorage`.

```
// check variable was set
var pageReloadedAlready = window.localStorage.getItem('reloaded');

$(window).on('mouseup', function(){

    if ($(window).width() <=775 && $(window).width() >= 481){
        if( ! pageReloadedAlready ){ 
            window.localStorage.setItem( 'reloaded', true ); // set variable to true
            location.reload();
        }
    } else if ($(window).width() <=480 && $(window).width() >= 300){
        if( ! pageReloadedAlready ){
            window.localStorage.setItem( 'reloaded', true );
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

You will want to make it more complex by invalidating after some time.

Comment: Thank you, I like this solution,
What do you mean by invalidating after some time? 

Like after a time interval its set to false so that it'll work again?

Comment: Yes, the setItem wouldn't be a true or false, but an object with true/false and a timestamp. This way after some time it would work again because you would check the timestamp.